# Is something wrong with this question

Tags: discussion, specific-question

After posting this question [Quick way to insert the Java 'for' loop in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771545/quick-way-to-insert-for-loop-in-eclipse?noredirect=1#comment27674265_18771545) I immediately got 2 downvotes.

Was it improper for SO?

If this question is improper also for SO-meta please let me explicitly know and don't just down-vote, but rather provide me with instruction what I did wrong.

Comment: Maybe it's my lack of knowledge of Eclipse, but your question doesn't make any sense. What do you mean by "insert for loop"?

Comment: To insert java for loop code. I maybe should have formatted it as code.

Comment: It appears you were looking for a sort of auto-complete feature, which isn't exactly clear from the question. Maybe you could explain that a little better in your question. Otherwise, we can't really know why people downvoted. They could have just downvoted because it's a basic question. Your question has a positive score right now, so I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Exactly. I assumed, that only people skilled with Eclipse would open it and try to answer and in that case it would be clear what I meant. I received at least 3 down-votes and it astonished me as I thought it was pretty useful question. I was just wondering if I did something wrong. Next time I will try to be more explicit.

Comment: That's always a bad plan. Try to write questions as if you're talking to someone who is intelligent but with only vague knowledge in your area. Remember questions aren't just between you and the people who answer the question;  they're for everyone who might have a similar question/interest

Comment: Even if it doesn't remove all the downvote, clarifying the question, even after accepting the answer, will still be beneficial for the site and whoever gets to see it.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is an online resource available to the general public; questions asked here should be of use to people other than you and the person who answers your question.

When you post a question about Eclipse on Stack Overflow, you're not just talking to the Eclipse experts, nor is the act of asking questions solely about you and your particular problem. You are also talking to the broader Stack Overflow community, who must parse your question and decide whether or not it is clear, answerable, and of use to other people who might find the question via Google.

Stack Overflow isn't the red phone to the Kremlin, in other words (the Kremlin being a room full of Eclipse experts, in this case).  That would be the Eclipse Chat Room, if such a room existed.

For these and other reasons, we still require a minimum level of skill and dexterity from people when they ask questions, regardless of our technical expertise (or lack thereof) in any given area.

Comment: But people shouldn't go traipsing around in areas they know little about evaluating questions other than the grossest of violations, right? I mean, if I start trying to just `R` questions since I'm confident in coding in general, I'm going to do a bad job. Only people familiar with the topic should be evaluating anything other than a question being grossly off-topic or unsalvageable.

Comment: Moderation does not, and should not, require technical knowledge of the subject matter.  In fact, moderation should not be based on technical knowledge at all.  That's what voting is for.  None of the criteria we use for evaluating a question requires expert knowledge.

Comment: How can you accurately vote "this is not useful" or submit a "must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved" on a topic you don't know?

Comment: Everything you mentioned here I took into consideration. I asked a question in a way that basic user of Eclipse with knowledge of java (or even programming at all for that matter) could understand it. We can discuss whether I expressed myself clearly or no (I hope for any suggestions). But than again, you cannot judge a question if you don't have minimal technical background (not even knowing that Eclipse have auto-completion feature for example). In fact I am still at loss what could provoke someone to vote itdown (duplicity of question?) and I would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: @LeNoob: The community tends to vote down and closevote questions that don't demonstrate prior effort. [This](http://theshyam.com/2009/07/eclipse-productivity-shortcuts/) was the second match in a Google Search for "eclipse java shortcut for loop".  And hey, I don't even know anything about Eclipse.